# VBA form controls action when it receives focus

Tags: excel, focus, label, controls, userform

I am trying to make a label display different instructions depending on which text or combo box currently has focus.

The problem is the label will only display the instruction text when I actually start typing something in the control, not when it is clicked on or tabbed to.

I have searched around and found a few suggestion such as (control is me.activecontrol...etc) but these don't solve my problem, and I don't want to force the focus with .setfocus. I just want it to display when the user focuses on the control on their own.

My current code: (I did try the other suggestions and made no progress)

```
Private Sub cmbPurposeID1_Change()    
     lblInstructions.Caption = "random text here."
End Sub'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Enter` events, eg

```
Private Sub cmbPurposeID1_Enter()    
     lblInstructions.Caption = "random text here."
End Sub
```

From VBA help: *Enter occurs before a control actually receives the focus from a control on the same form*

Comment: Ah great! Thanks. I had tried this before but I think at the time I must have had something else wrong that prevented it from working. Thanks a ton.